# What is the effect of this semi-colon after a try/catch macro?

Tags: c++

I am looking at some project which has

```
    PREPAID_TRY ;
```

That being defined elsewhere as

```
#define PREPAID_TRY try {
```

I think by using `;` above, the programmer basically cancelled use of `try`? Try does not take effect anymore, am I right?

But below it there is such code - and I wonder how does that compile when there is no `try` before it?

```
PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(pErrInfo, "(Connect)") ;
```

That defined as

```
#define PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(x,t) } \
  catch (const dErrorStruct& ex) {ex.FillErrorStruct(x);Log.LogPrintf(t ## " - %s", x->Description);}
```

Why does the above compile when the programmer used `;` in the first `try`?
The `catch` above doesn't have a preceding `try`, am I right?

Comment: `PREPAID_TRY` does work. Compiler simply replaces `PREPAID_TRY` with `try {`. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Remember that macros are nothing but text aliases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So suppose you have

```
#define PREPAID_TRY try {
#define PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(x,t) } \
  catch (const dErrorStruct& ex) {ex.FillErrorStruct(x);Log.LogPrintf(t ## " - %s", x->Description);}
```

And you write code such as

```
PREPAID_TRY;
  SomeFunction();
PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(pErrInfo, "(Connect)");
```

If you pretend to be the precompiler yourself, you can fill in the macro definitions and check that the compiler sees the following code, after reformatting:

```
try { 
  ; // Empty statement
  SomeFunction();  // Your original code is still part of the try
}  // Note this brace is part of PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG
catch (const dErrorStruct& ex) {
  ex.FillErrorStruct(pErrInfo);
  Log.LogPrintf("(Connect)" " - %s", pErrInfo->Description); // Note compile-time string concatenation
}
```

This gives a valid try/catch block. There is an empty statement (`;`) inside, but since the macros have been written such that you get a proper set of braces, that is not a problem. 
Also note that the `CATCH` macro takes care of the closing brace of the `try` construct.

Actually the semi-colon after `PREPAID_TRY` can be omitted, which will get rid of the unnecessary empty statement in the final code, but including it makes the line read more like a statement by itself and it is likely that the programmer who wrote it did not even notice he put it there (I sometimes find myself putting semi-colons in regular texts after having written C++ or C# for a whole day).

Probably what you are thinking of when you say "cancel the try block" is something like the following:

```
#define PREPAID_TRY if(not_out_of_memory())
#define PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(x,t) \
  else { raise_out_of_memory_exception(); }
```

Note that I had to replace the `try` with an `if` statement, because a try without braces is illegal in the first place (e.g. `try SomeFunction() catch { ... }` is not allowed), but for an if the braces in `if(...) { SomeFunction(); }` are optional if you only call one function. This leads to

```
if(not_out_of_memory())
  ;
SomeFunction();
else { raise_out_of_memory_exception(); }
```

where I indented your original `SomeFunction` code to the left to indicate how the compiler parses it. This does indeed lead to a compiler error, because when the compiler reaches `else`, there is no active `if` statement anymore. The only way to use this macro correctly would be including your own braces:

```
PREPAID_TRY {
  SomeFunction();
  ;;;;;; // Now you can put as many semicolons here as you like.
} 
PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(...)
```

Comment: hmm so ; doesn't cancel the try?

Comment: @user200312 There's no way you can do that. Where did you get the idea that you can "cancel" a try-block?

Comment: No, `;` is just an empty statement, it doesn't cancel anything - in fact it doesn't _do_ anything. You are probably confused by an example like `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);` (note the semi-colon) where the body of the `for` consists of the empty statement... but also there nothing is cancelled, it's just that all the work happens inside the for declaration.

Comment: @user200312 I added something about what I _think_ you mean to the answer. Please check if that clarifies your confusion.

Comment: @CompuChip: yes my confusion comes when you can cancel `if` and `for` using ;

Comment: @user200312 you should stop thinking of it as "cancelling" the `if`. And most coding standards for C++ I've seen require that you _always_ use braces for an `if`-statement, even if the body only has a single statement, precisely to avoid such errors when you want to nest the if or add a statement to it later.

Answer (score 0):

That macro is somewhat dangerous/confusing.

First you should know that the preprocessor is just a macro expansion language, that is it just cuts and glues the code that the actual compiler sees. That is when you write `PREPAID_TRY` the preprocessor changes that so that the compiler sees it as you've written `try {` instead, if you put a semi-colon after that the compiler sees `try { ;` instead. This is not a problem since the semi-colon is just an empty statement.

However the later is somewhat dangerous as when writing `PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG(pErrInfo, "(Connect)") ;` the compiler will see

```
catch (const dErrorStruct& ex) {ex.FillErrorStruct(pErrInfo);Log.LogPrintf("(Connect)" " - %s", x->Description);} ;
```

Also between the `PREPAID_TRY` and `PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG` there are a couple of looks-likea-a-statements. But it all expands to two statements, one compound `try-catch` statement and one empty statement. This means that what you're writing is not entirely what it looks like.

Now if you assume that you "know" that `PREPAID_TRY` and `PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG` is a compound statement you might do something like:

```
if( condition1 )
    PREPAID_TRY;
    some_code();
    PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG;
else
    some_other_code();
```

it would result in syntax error (since the semi-colon after `PREPAID_CATCH_WITH_LOG` will be an empty statment "canceling" the `if` statement. The code also looks odd, but that's a different thing.

Comment: Your example would trivially stop being dangerous if the `if` statement had a block following it, which would also read more naturally.

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes, of course, the example is a bit contrieved since it requires the programmer to "know" that the expansion should be a compound statement, but it doesn't look like that - so agreed it doesn't fit visually where one statement is expected.

Comment: It would be nicer if the macro were defined in a way so that you would be required to put the braces around the compound statements of the `try-catch` clause, but I can't find a definition that will do that nicely.

Comment: One could wrap the whole thing in a `do-while(0)` block, which would fix the `if` (making the whole thing into a single statement, though the resulting code would still look rather bad). Would be safer though.